# image with border inside fixed width container

Tags: css, image, containers, margin, padding

I have a fixed width container (div) and an image inside, this image should fit the container width but having a margin, like this:

[image]

I tried adding a padding to container, it makes container bigger.

My second attempt was adding a margin to the image, but it makes it go outside the container.

Both attempts are in this snippet:

```js
$('.result1').html('div is ' + $('.test1').width() + ' and image is ' + $('.test1 img').width());
$('.result2').html('div is ' + $('.test2').width() + ' and image is ' + $('.test2 img').width());
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #999;
}
img{
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}
.test1{
  padding:10px;
}
.test2 img{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test1'>
  <img src='http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png' />
</div>
<div class='result1'></div>
<div class='test2'>
  <img src='http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png' />
</div>
<div class='result2'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem.
You need to remove the margin you added to the image first.
Than give padding to your div container and also add box-sizing: border-box to it-

```js
$('.result1').html('div is ' + $('.test1').width() + ' and image is ' + $('.test1 img').width());
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
img{
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}
.test1{
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test1'>
  <img src='http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png' />
</div>
<div class='result1'></div>
<div class='test2'>
  <img src='http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png' />
</div>
<div class='result2'></div>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, I always avoid using padding because they make my designs bigger than what I want, using border-box made it easier. @WizardCoder answer is correct too, but I mark this one because the snippet make it easier to understand :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `box-sizing: border-box;` to your container and then use your padding solution. This CSS stops padding from adding to the size of an element.